# Viewing Code in Developer Mode Before it is Changed

Tags: php, html, firefox-developer-tools

Relatively new to using developer tools but this should be an easy question.
I want to inspect an element and view it's original value before it was changed via php or javascript rules applied to it.

My problem:
I'm helping design a profile page. In this profile page are links to that particular persons profile subpages. These values and links change according to the user that is logged in. What I want to find out (via developer tools) is what the value was before it was changed.

Note in the code below the a href and the yz-button-count class. These elements change according to the user that is logged in. I want to know what was in their place before those values were changed.

Thanks!

Code Snippet:

```
<a href="**http://lbbdevelop.wpengine.com/members/lbbdevelop/friends/requests**" class="yz-button-item yz-friends-btn">
    <span class="dashicons dashicons-groups"></span>
    <div class="yz-button-count">1</div>
</a>
```

Comment: I fail to understand the problem. Why wouldn't you be able to inspect the values when the page loads and then inspect them again when you make a new request?

Comment: It doesn't directly relate to the friend requests, that is just an example.
The a href link and the yz-button-count value "1" change according to the user value. Which means that their original code isn't "**http://lbbdevelop.wpengine.com/members/lbbdevelop/friends/requests**" or "1" but something else.
I want to use developer to find out the code that goes in place of these values that pulls the data.

Comment: It's not possible for the browser to show something that was changed strictly in PHP, because that is done entirely on the server prior to anything being sent to the browser (i.e. the browser never sees it). If it's being changed by JavaScript after the page is sent to the browser, then that is something which you could see.

Comment: Makyen - is there any way to find the original (code) value of these elements then?

Comment: I still don't understand what you want. What do you mean by "original (code) value"? Is this page ever accessible if a user is not logged in?

Answer (score 0):

You, as a client, cannot view a page before PHP processes it. That is done on the server before you as a client get it. To do that, ou'll need the original source code of the project. There is a very high chance that you will not be able to get that because it would open the site up to possible security breaches.

You can, however, view the page before JavaScript processes it because JavaScript is client-side. If you are using Chrome, when the page loads, just right click and select `View page source` or press `Ctrl + U`.

As far as "I want to know what was in their place before those values were changed." that gets tricky. They could be created with PHP before the page is given to you (Most likely). If they are created with JavaScript (Most likely not) you could trace them to sources by going through the JavaScript files of the website.